# Is it possible for the notifying thread to lock before the notified thread's wait to lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, operator-precedence

Example code from [std::condition_variable::notify_one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one).

**My question is**:
Is it possible for a **notifying thread** to **lock**, before the **notified thread's** `wait` function to lock, since the `notify` operation does not block current thread?

---

Code: (I delete the original comments)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;
int i = 0;
bool done = false;

void waits()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cout << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, []{return i == 1;}); //Waiting 
    std::cout << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
    done = true;
}

void signals()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Notifying falsely...\n";
    cv.notify_one(); //Notifying

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);//Is it possible for this line to execute
                                         //before cv.waits() in waits() tries to lock ?
    i = 1;
    while (!done)
    {
        std::cout << "Notifying true change...\n";
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one(); 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        lk.lock();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits), t2(signals);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to lock by notifying thread before the waiting one. But how does it make the code unsafe?

Comment: @bartop Yes, you are right.. It won't make the code unsafe even so. Btw, is there any rules that gurantee the execution order? Or it is simply undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your title question, yes. It is possible that the `signals` thread locks prior to the `waits` thread. But in answer to your real question, no, this won't cause a deadlock.

Why?

Because further in the example the mutex is released by `lk.unlock()`.  At this unlock the `waits` thread will have an opportunity to lock (then unlock again when waiting begins).

This loop continues until the `wait` thread has signified it is completed with the `done` boolean.

An example timing:

[image]

There are plenty of others, but in all cases the relevant objects and condition variables are protected by the mutex. You can't have data races or deadlocks. This example is sound.

Comment: Thank you Mr Fox. So the execution order of which is simply not guaranteed and I should not count on it right?

Comment: @Rick No it is not. That is why you should consider all of the possible orders to find if you can have data races or deadlocks.

Comment: Btw, I recheck the page of cppreference and notice that in the output section, it's writing "possible output", which may indirectly prove that. And in fact, the output cppreference shows and I get is : "the notifying thread lock first"...

Comment: @Rick, it can be worse then that as well. Read further into `condition_variable` you will find it can spuriously wake up for no reason at all. That's why you need the predicate (lambda in this case) that checks that the wait condition has actually been achieved. And you need the resources that the predicate uses to be protected by the mutex ...

Comment: I think this "(then unlock again when waiting begins)." is not right, once got notified, `cv.wait()` will lock and exit, then continue.  In this example, I think it only waits for once and unblock once. But it doesn't matter anyway :D.

Comment: Thank you for your diagram and extra information, very helpful for newbie. I know `condition_variable` may spuriously wake up, but never realize it could wake up for **no reason at all**... Where did you get the diagram btw?

Comment: @Rick You can make them here: https://sequencediagram.org/ As for the coment about waiting begins not being right, i am unsure qwhat you mean. It seems like you are saying the same thing that is in the timing diagram.

Comment: Oh, for the comment "...". I am saying about your answer. I think what you said about that is not right.

Comment: No it is correct. Wait: [*Atomically releases lock, blocks the current executing thread, and adds it to the list of threads waiting on \*this.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait)